# Building a general DynamoDBMarshalling for enums

Tags: java, generics, annotations, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using Amazon Web Services SDK for Java for DynamoDB; trying to suffice the interface for @DynamoDBMarshalling:

```
Class<? extends DynamoDBMarshaller<? extends Object>> marshallerClass();
```

I build a marshaller that receives any Enum:

```
public class EnumMarshaller<T extends Enum<T>> implements DynamoDBMarshaller<T>
{
    @Override
    public String marshall(T getterReturnResult)
    {
        return getterReturnResult.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public T unmarshall(Class<T> clazz, String obj)
    {
        return Enum.valueOf(clazz, obj);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to use the annotation on my field I can't figure it out:

```
public static enum MyEnum {BLA, BLA2}

@DynamoDBMarshalling(marshallerClass=EnumMarshaller<MyEnum>.class)
    public MyEnum getStatus()
    {
        return status;
    }
```

I can't call .class on a generic type and some other tries came up different errors.
I'm starting to think it's impossible with Amazon's contract...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following worked fine to me:

**The Marshaller:**

```
public class EnumMarshaller implements DynamoDBMarshaller<Enum> {
    @Override
    public String marshall(Enum getterReturnResult) {
        return getterReturnResult.name();
    }

    @Override
    public Enum unmarshall(Class<Enum> clazz, String obj) {
        return Enum.valueOf(clazz, obj);
    }
}
```

**In my table class with an enum:**

```
@DynamoDBMarshalling(marshallerClass=EnumMarshaller.class)
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "MyEnum")
public MyEnum getMyEnum() {
   return myEnum;
}
```

Comment: while this approach raises some warnings (both rawTypes and type safety), it does work.

Comment: Sadly I am unable to unit test this class as `marshaller.unmarshall(MyEnum.class, MyEnum.SOMETHING)` does not compile. Required Class<Enum> as 1st param.

Comment: As of version 1.10.59, the `aws-java-sdk` now provides an [`AbstractEnumMarshaller`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/199fba92dd0cdf4133f4aa5b08cfc10a11c27b31/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/AbstractEnumMarshaller.java) class which is a more robust version of this answer.

Answer (score 4):

I worked around this problem by sub-classing the JsonMarshaller with a specific class type:

```
public class FooMarshaller extends JsonMarshaller<Foo>
{
    // No impl required
}
```

Then the marshalling annotation is added to the data property like:

```
@DynamoDBMarshalling(marshallerClass = FooMarshaller.class)
public Set<Foo> getFoos()
{
    return foos;
}
```

A pain if you have to add many class types, but it works.

Comment: thanks, i ran into the same problem and this was a quick fix. Addionally I would just make this a inner "public static" class. so, that it need not be put in a seperate file.

Comment: I don't see how this helps for every enum type. The way I see it you need to sub class JsonMarshaller for every enum you create