# Testing general DynamoDBMarshalling for enums

Tags: java, generics, amazon-web-services, annotations, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDBMarsheller that is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063996/building-a-general-dynamodbmarshalling-for-enums).  It looks like:

```
public class EnumMarshaller implements DynamoDBMarshaller<Enum> {
    @Override
    public String marshall(Enum getterReturnResult) {
        return getterReturnResult.name();
    }

    @Override
    public Enum unmarshall(Class<Enum> clazz, String obj) {
        return Enum.valueOf(clazz, obj);
    }
}
```

Now I am stuck on trying to test it.  I have tried doing something along the lines of (where Status is a normal Enum):

```
    @Test
    public void shouldTurnStringToEnum() {
        final Class<? extends Enum> enumType = Status.class;

        assertThat(marshaller.unmarshall(enumType, "failed"), is(marshaller.marshall(Status.FAILED)));
    }
```

however I can't get the enum type variable right.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
EnumMarshaller marshaller = new EnumMarshaller();
```

Java will give compile time error if you pass enumType because it is Enum.class type as a parameter.

Try doing

```
DynamoDBMarshaller marshaller = new EnumMarshaller();
```

This should work.