# DynamoDBMarshaller to String List for a List of Enums

Tags: java, enums, amazon-dynamodb

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063996/building-a-general-dynamodbmarshalling-for-enums) about creating a generic DynamoDBMarshaller class that works for marshalling any Enum class. However, this won't work for lists of Enums.

I know I can write a marshaller that handles lists of Enums, but I have to write it to dynamo as a string (basically jsonify the list). This isn't ideal. For other class types, they can be annotated with `@DynamoDBDocument`, but this doesn't work on Enum types.

So, is there a way to marshall my Enum class as a string list in dynamo?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to specify the exact enum class you intend on serializing (and can't do something generic). Then you can use a library such as [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) to do the serialization for you:

```
package com.example.shared.models.marshallers;

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMarshaller;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.CollectionType;

import java.util.List;

public class EnumListMarshaller implements DynamoDBMarshaller<List<ENUM_NAME>> {
    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private static final ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer();

    @Override
    public String marshall(List<ENUM_NAME> obj) {
        try {
            return writer.writeValueAsString(obj);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to marshall list of enums to dynamo");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<ENUM_NAME> unmarshall(Class<List<ENUM_NAME>> clazz, String json) {
        final CollectionType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, ENUM_NAME.class);
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(json, type);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to unmarshall list of enums from dynamo");
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your DAO, you would add the annotation:

```
@DynamoDBMarshalling(marshallerClass = EnumListMarshaller.class)
```

Where "ENUM_NAME" is your enum class.